# Tensorflow model will not run in multithreaded cloud functions

Tags: tensorflow, flask, google-cloud-functions, python-multithreading

When i run this code on a locally on flask it works fine. but when i try to use functions framework to emulate cloud functions, or to deploy to cloud functions and run, the embed operation just gets stuck without an error forever. Ive increased cpu to 4 and memory to 8gb, it is not a compute power problem.

Reading around the forums are a little confusing, some mentioned it cant be done due to models having to be loaded in same thread as it is used, but other tutorials have shown themselves doing it.

Could someone help me out? I understand that it is recommended to deploy models via vertex ai or cloud run, but this is simply the easiest way for me rn, and im looking for a fix using cloud functions.

```
import flask
import os

from flask import Flask, request
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import os
import functions_framework
import time

class Embedding:
    def __init__(self):
        # module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"
        module_url = "./universal-sentence-encoder-large_5"
        # Time measurement for loading the model
        load_model_start = time.time()
        self.embed = hub.load(module_url)
        print(self.embed.predict)
       
        load_model_end = time.time()
        
        print(f"Model loaded in: {load_model_end - load_model_start:.2f} seconds")

        # Time measurement for loading the weights
        load_weights_start = time.time()
        self.is_event_model = pickle.load(open("./is_event_model/SVC_weights.pkl", "rb"))
        load_weights_end = time.time()
        print(f"Weights loaded in: {load_weights_end - load_weights_start:.2f} seconds")
    
    def embed(self, input):
        return self.embed.predict(input)
    
model = Embedding()

@functions_framework.http
def is_event(request: flask.Request) -> flask.Response:
    start_time = time.time()
    # Time measurement for retrieving the request data
    get_json_start = time.time()
    texts = request.get_json()
    get_json_end = time.time()
    print(f"Request data retrieved in: {get_json_end - get_json_start:.2f} seconds")

  
    results = model.embed(texts)

    return flask.jsonify(results.tolist())
```

Initialising the model inside is_event and calling it from there works, but i dont want to have to reinitialise the model for every call.